# validation tells that all my email addresses are invalid

Tags: javascript, regex

I do not know why it is telling me always that is an invalid email address even when it is correct.Any ideas?   [Demo on JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AkuXC/93/)

my form

```
  <form id="FormViewForm" method="post" action="/NewsletterMailer/subscribe/4" accept-charset="utf-8">
                <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST" />
                <input type="hidden" name="data[Form][id]" value="4" id="FormId" />
                <input type="hidden" name="data[Form][type]" value="1" id="FormType" />
                <input type="email" name="data[Form][e-mail]" value="" id="subscribe-email" placeholder="Enter your email..." required>
                    <input type="submit" value="+" class="large" id="subscribe-submit">
                        </form>
```

my custom.js

```
$('#FormViewForm').submit(function() {
    validateEmail($('input').val());
    return false;
});

function validateEmail(email) {
    var re = /^\s*[\w\-\+_]+(\.[\w\-\+_]+)*\@[\w\-\+_]+\.[\w\-\+_]+(\.[\w\-\+_]+)*\s*$/;
    if (re.test(email)) {
        if (email.indexOf('@c-e.com', email.length - '@c-e.com'.length) !== -1) {
            alert('Submission was successful.');
        } else {
            alert('Email must be a CE e-mail address (your.name@c-e.com).');
        }
    } else {
        alert('Not a valid e-mail address.');
    }
}
```

Comment: My solution to this issue is simple, don't validate the email, just check it has a `@` and send a confirmation email; the **real** validation.

Comment: if I had to take a wild guess, it would be this line: `if (email.indexOf('@c-e.com', email.length - '@c-e.com'.length) !== -1)`. It doesn't make sense

Comment: @elclanrs maybe a bit of quick val, like spaces? at least one dot on right-half. `^[^ ]@[^ ]\.[^ ]$`

Comment: @remu: Yeah, oversimplifying, I typically use something like `/[^@]+@[^@]/`

Comment: @elclanrs yeah -- although perhaps both not @ and not space. :)

Answer (score 4):

Simply a jQuery selector issue, you're missing a `#`.

```
validateEmail($('#subscribe-email').val());
```

Your function receives `undefined` as an e-mail and the regex fails.

You could also use pure JavaScript. (Note that `document.getElementById` does not require the `#`, which might have caused the confusion.)

```
validateEmail(document.getElementById('subscribe-email').value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use right selector like 
If you want to user id as selector

```
validateEmail($('#subscribe-email').val());
```

Or you can also use input tag as selector

```
validateEmail($('input[type=email]').val());
```

The id selector will be strong to all browser and also safe to use

Please try this code

```
$('#FormViewForm').submit(function() {
    validateEmail($('#subscribe-email').val());
    return false;
});

function validateEmail(email) {
    var re = /^\s*[\w\-\+_]+(\.[\w\-\+_]+)*\@[\w\-\+_]+\.[\w\-\+_]+(\.[\w\-\+_]+)*\s*$/;
    if (re.test(email)) {
        if (email.indexOf('@c-e.com', email.length - '@c-e.com'.length) !== -1) {
            alert('Submission was successful.');
        } else {
            alert('Email must be a CE e-mail address (your.name@c-e.com).');
        }
    } else {
        alert('Not a valid e-mail address.');
    }
}
```